# What is a substitute for spry?

Tags: baking, substitutions

I have an old fruit cake recipe and it calls for spry, what can I substitute for spry?

Answer (score 3):

Use any other shortening, Spry is just a brand name (not being produced any more).

We discussed Spry just a while ago in this post: [Mystery ingredient in cookies with cream tartar](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85407/mystery-ingredient-in-cookies-with-cream-tartar)

Answer (score 3):

Years ago I also used spry. But now I use Crisco and it works exactly the same!